# Laravel-echo и TypeScript

Tags: laravel, typescript, webpack, webpack2, laravel-elixir

Здравствуйте.

Изучаю ts (v2.3.2): столкнулся с проблемами импорта библиотек. Собираю проект webpack'ом (laravel-mix: 0.8.3, webpack: 2.2.0)

Проблемы:

1. `import Echo from "laravel-echo";`

   > Cannot find module "laravel-echo"
2. `import Echo from "../../../../bower_components/laravel-echo/src/echo";`

   > Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'
3. Пытаясь решить п. 2 с ссылкой
   https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039:
   `let Echo = require('../../../../bower_components/laravel-echo/src/echo');`

   По-прежнему ошибка

   > Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

И еще: не нашел деклараций для laravel-echo. Может плохо искал? Если у кого-то есть - поделитесь, пожалуйста?

Спасибо за уделенное внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там, видимо, используется какая-то старая версия Typescript, где можно было так делать. Или просто более "слабые" настройки у компилятора.

Попробуйте подключать модуль не из папки `src`, а из папки `dist`.

Если папки `dist` в пакете нет - значит, вы загрузили не специально собранный разработчиками пакет, а исходники с гитхаба. В таком случае используйте для загрузки пакета не `bower`, а `npm`.

Comment: благодарю за скорый ответ. "Перенес" библиотеку из bower_components в node_modules - помогло в плане подключения библиотеки, но методов "не видит". (например: "Cannot read property 'private' of undefined"). Если можете, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

В любом случае - огромное спасибо!

Comment: спасибо.

По невнимательности упустил несколько моментов - то, что не работало - завелось.